# Swift function that takes in array giving error: '@lvalue $T24' is not identical to 'CGFloat'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cgfloat

So I'm writing a lowpass accelerometer function to moderate the jitters of the accelerometer. I have a CGFloat array to represent the data and i want to damp it with this function:

```
// Damps the gittery motion with a lowpass filter.
func lowPass(vector:[CGFloat]) -> [CGFloat]
{
    let blend:CGFloat = 0.2

    // Smoothens out the data input.
    vector[0] = vector[0] * blend + lastVector[0] * (1 - blend)
    vector[1] = vector[1] * blend + lastVector[1] * (1 - blend)
    vector[2] = vector[2] * blend + lastVector[2] * (1 - blend)

    // Sets the last vector to be the current one.
    lastVector = vector

    // Returns the lowpass vector.
    return vector
}
```

In this case, lastVector is defined as follows up at the top of my program:

```
var lastVector:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The three lines in the form vector[a] = ... give me the errors. Any ideas as to why i am getting this error?

Comment: As I side note, I am passing it a [CGFloat] array

Comment: What errors are you getting? What lines are the errors occuring?

Comment: The error is in the title and its the exact same for all three of those lines. Also lastVector as mentioned above is a CGFloat array and is defined as a global var. It is not the source of the error because without it, the same error persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code seems to compile if you pass the array with the `inout` modifier:

```
func lowPass(inout vector:[CGFloat]) -> [CGFloat] {
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure whether that's a bug or not. Instinctively, if I pass an array to a function I expect to be able to modify it. If I pass with the `inout` modifier, I'd expect to be able to make the original variable to point to a new array - similar to what the `&` modifier does in C and C++.

Maybe the reason behind is that in Swift there are mutable and immutable arrays (and dictionaries). Without the `inout` it's considered immutable, hence the reason why it cannot be modified.

**Addendum 1 - It's not a bug**

@newacct says that's the intended behavior. After some research I agree with him. But even if not a bug I originally considered it wrong (*read up to the end for conclusions*).

If I have a class like this:

```
class WithProp {
    var x : Int = 1

    func SetX(newVal : Int) {
        self.x = newVal
    }
}
```

I can pass an instance of that class to a function, and the function can modify its internal state

```
var a = WithProp()

func Do1(p : WithProp) {
    p.x = 5 // This works
    p.SetX(10) // This works too
}
```

without having to pass the instance as `inout`. 
I can use `inout` instead to make the `a` variable to point to another instance:

```
func Do2(inout p : WithProp) {
    p = WithProp()
}

Do2(&a)
```

With that code, from within `Do2` I make the `p` parameter (i.e. the `a` variable) point to a newly created instance of `WithProp`.

The same cannot be done with an array (and I presume a dictionary as well). To change its internal state (modify, add or remove an element) the `inout` modifier must be used. That was counterintuitive.

**But everything gets clarified after reading [this excerpt](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_110) from the swift book**:

> Swift’s String, Array, and Dictionary types are implemented as structures. This means that strings, arrays, and dictionaries are copied when they are assigned to a new constant or variable, or when they are passed to a function or method.

So when passed to a func, it's not the original array, but a copy of it - Hence any change made to it (even if possible) wouldn't be done on the original array.

So, in the end, my original answer above is **correct** and the experienced behavior is **not a bug**

Many thanks to @newacct :)

Comment: yw - but that sounds like a bug, so I think you should file a radar

Comment: It's absolutely not a bug. This is the correct behavior. In order to modify an Array (since Xcode 6 beta 3), it needs to be assignable, not a constant (modifying it is semantically equivalent to assigning a new array). The only way that a parameter is assignable is if it's declared `var` (in which case changes to it does not affect the caller) or `inout` (in which case changes to it does affect the variable in the caller's scope. All the sort functions now have to take the array as `inout` for this reason.

Comment: @newacct thanks for pointing that out. Added some notes to my original answer explaining why it is not a bug

Answer (score 6):

Since Xcode 6 beta 3, modifying the contents of an `Array` is a mutating operation. You cannot modify a constant (i.e. `let`) Array; you can only modify a non-constant (i.e. `var`) Array.

Parameters to a function are constants by default. Therefore, you cannot modify the contents of `vector` since it is a constant. Like other parameters, there are two ways to be able to change a parameter:

- Declare it `var`, in which case you can assign to it, but it is still passed by value, so any changes to the parameter has no effect on the calling scope.
- Declare it `inout`, in which case the parameter is passed by reference, and any changes to the parameter is just like you made the changes on the variable in the calling scope.

You can see in the Swift standard library that all the functions that take an Array and mutate it, like `sort()`, take the Array as `inout`.

P.S. this is just like how arrays work in PHP by the way

Comment: Modifying the array is referring to modifying the size of it, not a subscript access. The size of the array is not modified.

Comment: @wbennett: Not anymore. They changed it.

Comment: I am updating to beta 3 ATM. What happens when you run this with `xcrun swift`? let arr = [0,1,2]; arr[0] = 2

Comment: @wbennett: It won't let you

Comment: Awesome. Step away for a week and you feel like you live under a rock. Can you edit it so I can retract my down vote? I down voted doing what you said couldn't be done, thinking I had the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The following worked for Xcode Beta 2. Apparently, the syntax and behavior of arrays has changed in Beta 3. You can no longer modify the contents of an array with subscripts if it is immutable (a parameter not declared inout or var):

**Not valid with the most recent changes to the language**

The only way I could get it to work in the play ground was change how you are declaring the arrays. I suggest trying this (works in playground):

```
import Cocoa
let lastVector: CGFloat[] = [0.0,0.0,0.0]

func lowPass(vector:CGFloat[]) -> CGFloat[] {
    let blend: CGFloat = 0.2
    vector[0] = vector[0] * blend + lastVector[0] * ( 1 - blend)
    vector[1] = vector[1] * blend + lastVector[1] * ( 1 - blend)
    vector[2] = vector[2] * blend + lastVector[2] * ( 1 - blend)
    return vector
}

var test = lowPass([1.0,2.0,3.0]);
```

Comment: Interesting — those should be equivalent, so it sounds like it might be a bug with the newer array type syntax.

Comment: I would agree, running under `xcrun swift` gives me a segfault when I try to use that syntax. Even though the language manual gives explicit examples of the [Type] usage.

Comment: That syntax is invalid in the new swift, but i should report that bug

Comment: Indeed. That might partially explain why passing the vector as inout works, if the bug affects the other case only

Comment: Definitely not a bug. This is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly as a followup for future reference, @newacct's answer is the correct one. Since the original post showed a function that returns an array, the correct answer to this question is to *tag the parameter with `var`*:

```
func lowPass(var vector:[CGFloat]) -> [CGFloat] {
    let blend:CGFloat = 0.2

    // Smoothens out the data input.
    vector[0] = vector[0] * blend + lastVector[0] * (1 - blend)
    vector[1] = vector[1] * blend + lastVector[1] * (1 - blend)
    vector[2] = vector[2] * blend + lastVector[2] * (1 - blend)

    // Sets the last vector to be the current one.
    lastVector = vector

    // Returns the lowpass vector.
    return vector
}
```