# Swift Array handling of Subclasses

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, subclass, implicit-conversion

If I have a variable declared like `var gameBoard: [Piece] = []`, is there any way to add a subclass of `Piece`, called `Queen`, to the array?

I am using `Piece` to represent all pieces. Queen, Pawn, Bishop and such are all subclasses of Piece, and should be included on the board.

I remember doing this frequently in Objective C, where subclasses were able to be used in place of the superclass. But in my first attempts, it I am getting an error saying

```
'@lvalue $T11' is not identical to 'Piece`
```

Is this not possible anymore? Or would there need to be some use of generics that I cannot think of right now?

**Edit**

Here is the implementation of my board, including only the relevant parts.

```
struct GameBoard{

    var board: [[Piece]]

    init() {
        board = []
        for _ in 0...7{
            var collumn: [Piece] = []
            for _ in 0...7{
                var piece = Piece(player: .None, board: self)
                collumn.append(piece)
            }
            board.append(collumn)
        }
    }

    subscript(coords:(Int, Int) ) -> Piece {
        return board[coords.1][coords.0]
    }
}
```

The code that fails is

```
var board = GameBoard()
var q = Queen(player: .Black, board: board)
board[(4,5)] = q         //Throws the error
board.board[5][4] = q    //Works
```

It seems to me that these two should work the same way. It may be an issue with the subscripting, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: This works fine in Swift. Can you give an actual example that does not work as expected?

Answer (score 5):

Just to followup on your edits, this works fine in Swift. For example:

```
class Piece {}
class Bishop : Piece {}
let pieces: [Piece] = [Bishop()]
```

Do you have an example that does not work?

As a note, when you see `@lvalue $T##` in your errors, it often means you're trying to modify a constant. An easy way to make that mistake is to try to modify an array that was passed to you and that you did not mark `var`. For example, see [Swift function that takes in array giving error: '@lvalue $T24' is not identical to 'CGFloat'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707245/swift-function-that-takes-in-array-giving-error-lvalue-t24-is-not-identical).

Comment: Sorry, I should use a different example. I will update my question.

Comment: I added the code that is failing, and relevant implementation details. Hopefully this might clear things up.

Comment: Seems that I forgot to create a setter for the subscript. That might be what is making it read-only

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write it. Includes answer to the question about subscripting, and for bonus, uses a Coords struct in place of tuples (allows implementation of Printable for example) and uses optionals for each square (allows nil to be used as the representation of an empty square.)

```
class Piece : Printable {
    var description: String { get { return "Piece" } }
}

class Queen : Piece {
    override var description: String { get { return "Queen" } }
}

struct Coords : Printable {
    let column: Int
    let row: Int

    init(_ column: Int, _ row: Int) {
        self.column = column
        self.row = row
    }

    var description: String { get { return "Coords(\(column), \(row))" } }
}

struct GameBoard {
    var board: [[Piece?]]

    init() {
        board = []
        for _ in 1...8 {
            board.append(Array<Piece?>(count: 8, repeatedValue:nil))
        }
    }

    subscript(c: Coords) -> Piece? {
        get {
            return board[c.column][c.row]
        }

        set (newValue) {
            board[c.column][c.row] = newValue
        }
    }
}

func testGameBoard() {
    var board = GameBoard()

    board[Coords(4, 5)] = Queen()

    func printSquare(coords: Coords) {
        if let p = board[coords] {
            println("At \(coords) is a \(p)")
        } else {
            println("At \(coords) is an empty square")
        }
    }

    printSquare(Coords(4, 5)) // Prints: At Coords(4, 5) is a Queen
    printSquare(Coords(4, 6)) // Prints: At Coords(4, 6) is an empty square
}
```

Comment: Is it really possible with {struct Coords : Printable}?

Comment: @wagashi Yes, it absolutely is, but if you're trying to test the above in a playground, note that the most recent Xcode beta still doesn't honor the Printable protocol for instances displayed within the playground.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `Queen` is a subclass of `Piece` then there would be no problem.  As such:

```
class Piece {}
class Queen : Piece {}

class Board {
  var board : [[Piece?]] = 
    { var board : [[Piece?]] = []
      for _ in 0..<8 { board.append (Array<Piece?>(count: 8, repeatedValue:nil)) }
      return board } ()

  subscript (row:Int, col:Int) -> Piece? {
    get { return board[row][col] }
    set { board[row][col] = newValue }}
}
```

and then use as:

```
 23> let board = Board()
 24> b[0,4] = Queen()
 25> b[7,4] = Queen()
 26> b
$R0: Board = {
  board = 8 values {
    [0] = 8 values {
      [0] = nil
      [1] = nil
      [2] = nil
      [3] = nil
      [4] = Some
      [5] = nil
      [6] = nil
      [7] = nil
    } ...
```